# IText7 html2Pdf error for HTML table with row header colspan attribute

Tags: itext7

I am using iText7 (html2Pdf) to convert a HTML to PDF document. When ever there is a table with "th" tag containing "colspan" attribute, the library throws an exception.

Here is my table

```
<table class=" doc_table ">
    <thead class=" doc_thead ">
    <tr class=" doc_row ">
         <th align="center" class=" doc_entry " colspan="3"> <p class=" doc_p ">Instrument system </p> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class=" doc_rowsection ">
        <th align="center" class=" doc_entry " scope="rowgroup"><p class=" doc_p ">Instrument system </p></th>
        <th align="center" class=" doc_entry " scope="rowgroup"><p class=" doc_p ">Instrument system </p></th>
        <th align="center" class=" doc_entry " scope="rowgroup"><p class=" doc_p ">Instrument system </p></th>
    </tr>
    <tr class=" doc_row ">
        <th align="left" class=" doc_entry "><p class=" doc_p ">Product </p></th>
        <th class=" doc_entry "><p class=" doc_p ">Catalog no. </p></th>
        <th class=" doc_entry "><p class=" doc_p ">Quantity </p></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class=" doc_tbody ">
     //body contents
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.wrapelement.TableWrapper.addCellToTable(TableWrapper.java:85)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.wrapelement.TableWrapper.addHeaderCell(TableWrapper.java:60)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.tags.TableTagWorker.processTagChild(TableTagWorker.java:57)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:161)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:143)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:143)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.visit(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:143)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.DefaultHtmlProcessor.processDocument(DefaultHtmlProcessor.java:114)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.Attacher.attach(Attacher.java:18)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(HtmlConverter.java:108)
    at PdfCreator.createPdf(PdfCreator.java:58)
```

When the first "tr" is removed from "thead", then the exception is not seen. The same "tr" tag when present in the "tbody" also there are no exceptions thrown. What could be the issue?

Comment: The issue is in `pdfHTML` itself. There was a bug with processing header/footer cells with colspans. The bug has already been fixed in `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeySubach

Comment: When can I expect this fix to be released?

Comment: @ArjunB Sometime this week or the next

Comment: Hi @SamuelHuylebroeck, any updates on the bug fix release?

Comment: @ArjunB pdfHTML's release was pushed back for now